# Need gadget to access calendar and nothing else

Tags: portable

A high school student with OCD needs a portable gadget that will display his Google Calendar (or something similar).  If it will allow him to *update* his calendar as well, that would be icing on the cake.

What it should **not** be able to do:

- send a photograph
- look up information on the internet
- send or receive chat messages
- send email
- place or receive phone calls

How would it get updated calendar information?  Perhaps wifi, perhaps USB, perhaps infrared, perhaps some sort of syncing procedure -- I'm a little vague about this.  Perhaps an adult could do a twice a day sync with a computer.  Would a Personal Digital Assistant fit the bill?

Ideally it would be smaller than a laptop.

We've tried a laptop with child safety filtering -- he manages to find loopholes.

Help with tagging would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Making better use of parental controls on a more locked-down mobile system, e.g. screen pinning on a cheap Android tablet, seems like the clearest solution to me. Finding a workaround should be quite difficult if configured properly.